# What is the opposite block of BatchBlock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

**Given**:

A list of ids of emails

**What I'm doing**:

With the BatchBlock group ids and call a Transformblock for each block the simplified transformblock looks like this:

```
var readBatch = new TransformBlock<List<int>, IEnumerable<Email>>(idList =>
{
    List<Email> mails = new List<Email>();
    foreach(var id in idList)
    {
        mails.Add(new Email(id));
    }
    return mails;
});
```

Now my next TransformBlock is defined like this

```
TransformBlock<Email,EMail> filterStep;
```

**What I search**:
So I need a block which allows me to get a collection as source and returns N-Elements as result. So in this case a block which receives a `IEnumerable<Email>` and returns `Email` foreach entryin the enumeration.

So what I search is the opposite of the BatchBlock but i can't find it. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The block you need is [`TransformManyBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784(v=vs.110).aspx). You return an `IEnumerable<Email>` from the the block's func and it automatically transfers each item individually:

```
var transformManyBlock = new TransformManyBlock<IEnumerable<Email>, Email>(emails => emails);
```

Answer (score 2):

[TransformManyBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194710.aspx) might be what you are looking for. It takes TInput and returns IEnumerable (1:n).