# BufferBlock getting blocked on OutputAvailableAsync

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am new to using TPL.  I've been able to implement a simple post / receive transaction on a BufferBlock but when I try to go asynchronous, I get hung.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying.

Declare the message buffer (made it global)

```
Dim msgBuffer As New BufferBlock(Of String)
```

A simple function to post the messages which is just a list of file names in a directory

```
Private Sub PostMessagesToBuffer()

    filesList = Directory.GetFiles(txtBoxSrcFilesDir.Text, fileFilter).ToList
    For Each file In filesList
        msgBuffer.Post(file)
    Next
    msgBuffer.Complete()
End Sub
```

I created this function for processing the messages:

```
Private Async Function ProcessMessagesAsync() As Task(Of Integer)

    Dim msgsProcessed = 0

    While Await msgBuffer.OutputAvailableAsync
        Dim msg = msgBuffer.Receive
        Console.WriteLine(msg)
        msgsProcessed += 1
    End While

    Return msgsProcessed

End Function
```

Then just this set of calls to run it all.

```
Dim msgProcessor = ProcessMessagesAsync()
PostMessagesToBuffer()
msgProcessor.Wait()
Console.writeLine("Processed " & msgProcessor.Result & " Messages.")
```

I can debug and see the messages getting added to the buffer but the "While Await" never gets the signal that a message is available on the queue.  It just sits there, never getting into the loop to do the work on the message.   Am I missing something rather simple here?

Comment: It is a clear case of deadlock, the code cannot get past the While loop to arrive at PostMessagesToBuffer().  This normally happens on another thread.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console application? Windows Forms?

Comment: It’s a windows forms application.

Comment: That makes sense. Your code shouldn't deadlock in a Console application. But the Windows Forms applications install a synchronization context in the UI thread, to force the async workflow to continue in the UI thread after an `await`, which is very helpful but introduces the possibility of deadlocks if the UI thread becomes blocked for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. Deadlocks are pretty common when [blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead of `Wait`:

```
msgProcessor.Wait()
```

...it is safer to `Await`:

```
Await msgProcessor
```

Also the [`DataflowBlock.Receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receive) is a blocking method. The proper method to use after awaiting the `DataflowBlock.OutputAvailableAsync` is the method [`DataflowBlock.TryReceive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.tryreceive).

I should also note that retrieving manually the elements of a `DataflowBlock` is feasible but uncommon. Usually the last block in a dataflow pipeline is an [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1), that doesn't generate output.

Comment: I’ll give that a try and see if that helps. I did try to switch to using ActionBlock attached to a processing method. That seems to work fine.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714155/tpl-how-do-i-split-and-merge-the-dataflow/58751948#58751948) answer where I implemented an extension method `ToListAsync` very similar to yours `ProcessMessagesAsync`, using the method `TryReceive` instead of `Receive`.